Will or would in the following sentences
He said he will come tomorrow.
He said he would come tomorrow.
Which sentence is correct ?

Google "backshifting" for numerous examples of when to change the present tense to the past tense in reporting what someone has said.

If he told us on Tuesday that he would come on Friday, both versions are valid; it's Thursday today.
However, if he told us on Wednesday that he changed his mind, then only the second version is valid when we give an indirect quote of his original statement.
